# Where should I put code that performs statistical analysis on models in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

In my controller, I need to generate data that will be charted. In order to get this data, I need to both perform queries and process the returned data. Right now I have a Stats class in a StatsHelper module, but I realize this is incorrect. The Stats class is used in multiple controllers and deals with multiple models, albeit focusing mainly on one. Where should this logic go?

I'm leaning towards putting it in a model of its own within a Stats namespace, but it seems odd to work with other models within a model. I don't want to put it in a lib, since it is definitely application specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate Stats class to keep code logically separated and easy to identify and rework in the future (rather than it being co-mingled amongst other code logic).

In the class in which you are performing stats against, ie. object.some_stat, I'd define specific methods that will call the Stats class. If you have many models that you will perform the stats against, then I'd define all of these methods within a module and then include the module in each class that I want to use stats against. I've found this keeps the code really clean.

The easiest is to create your Stat module, and include in it every class that you want the methods.

```
module Stat
  def sum
  ..
  end
end

class Something
  include Stat
end
```